# Scid vs PC Score Graph

Tags: evaluation, scid, open-source

Is it possible to modify the source code to change the display of the score graph so that you are always at the bottom? Currently, the player playing White is always at the bottom.

Comment: I suggest you look at the code that generates the opening report, as the diagram can be rotated to show the position of the black at the bottom.

Comment: Of course! It's possible to modify.

Comment: @caissalover How?